# React HOC has a Typescript error as a class component but not as a function component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components, react-typescript

typescript - v3.9.7

I have a HOC that pass additional props to the component:

```
import React from 'react';

interface IWithOwner {
    owner: string;
}

type IWithoutOwner<T extends IWithOwner> = Omit<T, keyof IWithOwner> & {owner?: never};

// CORRECT
export function withOwnerOne<TProps extends IWithOwner>(Component: React.ComponentType<TProps>) {
    const ComponentWithOwner: React.FunctionComponent<IWithoutOwner<TProps>> = (props) => {
        return (
            <Component
                owner="Tom"
                {...props}
            />
        );
    }

    return ComponentWithOwner;
}

// ERROR
export function withOwnerTwo<TProps extends IWithOwner>(Component: React.ComponentType<TProps>) {
    return class extends React.Component<IWithoutOwner<TProps>> {
        render() {
            return (
                // '{ owner: string; } & Readonly<IWithoutOwner<TProps>> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'
                // is assignable to the constraint of type 'TProps', but 'TProps' could be
                // instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'IWithOwner'.
                <Component
                    owner="Tom"
                    {...this.props}
                />
            )
        }
    }
}
```

`withOwnerOne` that uses Function component works correctly. While `withOwnerTwo` that uses class component has an error. Why do they work differently?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#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)

[Same case with functions works correctly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHVhgBYHkDuI0yA3gFDKXID2h0AXMgM5hSgDmA3GQL5llgAngAcUGLNmoBXMASJQAPABVkEAB6QQAEyZpMOOdAB8yALzJcAWyzKANMgDWEQdRh6JhqCYBkpWvIB+RiIAN2gebjJ1YWooMGQYKRAEMGBqEGR8DzooXCJlAAUoamFddU0ddwMcowAKCioEOAAbZoAjRAdGWuFi0sYlIpKmAEozExDqYC0yMfIqZCgIMCkoDMTk1PTauCh2JkZxHGlZHMK+piM5hoXKJtaOhAdakn8GZAByJWpLD-sAOkBu32PBG3AWfD4UTUMTiCSSKTSGSy1XkSnw1HOw1UGgg2l0RzwNXqC3u7U63V6wwGQ1KY1MEymM2uCyWKzWyAQzTgTF081ulCW2mgOz2ByqkhknixpSupBuAsaLXJTxebygjC+Pz+yEB-2BTFB4MVfAhvDIQA)

Comment: For me it fails in both cases

Comment: @Drag13 Maybe it depends on typescript version or something else. Have you looked playground link?

Comment: It was on the playground, after I changed some symbols and undo the change

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in `props` type.

In first example, `FunctionComponent`, type of `props` is: `IWithoutOwner<TProps> & { children?: ReactNode };`

```js
interface IWithOwner {
  owner: string;
}

type IWithoutOwner<T extends IWithOwner> = Omit<T, keyof IWithOwner> & {
  owner?: never;
};

function withOwnerTwo<TProps extends IWithOwner>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<TProps>
) {
  const ComponentWithOwner: React.FunctionComponent<IWithoutOwner<TProps>> = (
    props
  ) => {

    //  React.PropsWithChildren<IWithoutOwner<TProps>>   -->    IWithoutOwner<TProps> & { children?: ReactNode };
    const x = props; 
    return <Component owner="Dmitry" {...props} />;
  };

  return ComponentWithOwner;
}
```

In second, `props` has a bit different type:

`Readonly<IWithoutOwner<TProps>> & Readonly<{children?: React.ReactNode;}>`

```js
function withOwnerOne<TProps extends IWithOwner>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<TProps>
) {
  class Wrapper extends React.Component<IWithoutOwner<TProps>> {
    render() {
      //Readonly<IWithoutOwner<TProps>> & Readonly<{children?: React.ReactNode;}>
      const props = this.props; 

      return <Component owner="Dmitry" {...props} />;
    }
  }

  return Wrapper;
}
```

Now, you may think that the problem is in `Readonly` modifier.
`Readonly` does not cause the error. I strongly believe, that error is caused by contravariance.

Because type of `props` is taken from component context, and props generic is placed in differen positions in above components.

I'm open to criticizm, so feel free to point my mistakes.

Covariance/variance/invariance - are too complicated topic for me, I more feel it than understand. So, I will be happy if you point me the correct way.